# Is it possible to have a conditional inside a conditional with Java

Tags: java

I'm currently enrolled in my first ever computer science class and I'm trying to code a simple program where there are three possible answers, and if the user guesses the correct answer, they get a certain message.  The way the program should work is if they guess the correct answer, they get a generic message saying "you win", and then if they won by guessing a, they get message x, if they won by guessing b, they get message y, and if they won by guessing c, they get message c.  I currently have

```
if (result.equal(pick)) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

to get the "you win" and "you lose" messages, but is there a way to put another condition inside the first line so that if pick was a, they get message x, and so on?

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You can map an input to a certain response: `map.put("a", "x");`, then you simply retrieve the response that was mapped to whatever the input was: `pick = "a"; map.get(pick); // returns "x"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can put any statement you want in the if-block, so yes, you can put another if-elseif-else inside the if-block and/or else-block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
if (result.equal(pick)) {...
   if (pick.equal(a)){...}
   else if (pick.equal(b)){...}
   else if (pick.equal(c)){...}
   else {...}
} else {... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain conditions together using `&&` which requires all conditions to be true:

```
if (result.equal(pick) && result.equal(pickTwo)) {
```

or `||` to require only one of the conditions to be true

```
if (result.equal(pick) || result.equal(pickTwo)) {
```

Alternatively, you could use a `switch`

```
switch (string result){
    case "Answer":
        System.out.println("You did it!");
        break;
    case "Answer2":
        System.out.println("You did it!");
        break;
    default:
         "you lose!";
          break;
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 0):

You can place **multiple conditionals in an if statement block**, this may be what your looking for.

```
// The if conditional can hold Boolean logic.
if (result.equals(pick) && result.equals(x)) {..
}
else {...}
```

Another alternative is placing the if in the if (**nested ifs**)

```
if (result.equals(pick)) {...
  if(result.equals(x){...
  }
} else {...}
```

How I would approach this is by **using a hash map** to hold all of my answers.

```
Map<String,String> answers = new HashMap<String,String>(){{
  answers.put(a,x);
  answers.put(b,y);
  answers.put(c,c); 
}};

result = userInput;
if (answers.get(result) != null)
    System.out.println(answers.get(result));
else 
      System.out.println(defaultResponse);
```

Using the hashmap is my favorite route, because I can use that map(dictionary) to hold all potential results. It's located in one place. It feels more object-oriented to me. The last solution uses a static initializer and generates an anonymous class behind the scenes.

Comment: True. These are available at your utility. But the nested if statement is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct it *is* possible to nest if-then-else statements.

It would be considered [bad practice](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/refactoring-deeply-nested-code/231500074) to nest to too many levels though. For now, you do not need to worry about that so much. Just make sure the code is reasonably readable and works.

The other potentially useful option open to you would be to use a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

A switch statement examines the value of a variable and allows you to take different actions based on the value. See link above.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can solve this little exercise.

If you are after multiple conditional linked statements, I also suggest looking at switch-case statements, especially as Java 7+ now supports Strings e.g.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Switch statements are cleaner.

Another way to solve this exercise could be to create a HashMap with the Key being the answer, and the value being the message.

Then all you need to do is look for the key (answer).  If it exists, respond with "You Win" + the keys_value.

```
HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();

results.put("A", "messgae A!");
results.put("B", "message B!");
results.put("C", "message C!");

String answer = "A";

if (results.containsKey(answer)){
    System.out.println("You Win! " + results.get(answer));
} else {
    System.out.println("You loose");
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html